# Click box on shapes not right size in javafx for translated polygon

Tags: java, javafx

I am making an app with javafx and I put Polygon shapes into a Pane and define the shapes (one for example below) as

```
shape.getPoints().addAll(new Double[] { ... points ... });
shape.setTranslateX(...);
shape.setTranslateY(...);

setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        System.out.println(hex.getResource().toString());
        hex.pressed();
    }
});
```

Then I add the shape to my pane

```
pane.getChildren().addAll(shape);
```

But when I click on the shapes, it seems like the click area is covering more than just the shape. It is covering up other click areas, so I am unable to click on some shapes, and I am accidentally clicking on others. But the shapes themselves are in the right position and look fine. They aren't physically covering each other up. Please let me know how I would fix the click area.

Also, I can't use the other layout classes since my shapes need to be put in a location explicitly, not just in a grid or next to each other.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you are looking for `shape.setPickOnBounds(false);`. It might help if you could create a simple [MCVE].

Comment: What is `hex` and why are you setting the event handler not on the shape?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is clipping.

Go ahead and add this to your code and that should resolve your issue.

```
pane.setClip(shape);
```

As for your second issue, I'm not sure what you're asking.